# avconv stops streaming after some time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, avconv

I am using raspberry-pi board and a usb camera attached with it. i use avconv tool to capture live video from camera and streaming it on network using rtp protocol.

My command on server(raspberry-pi board) is as below:

**avconv -f video4linux2 -s 160x120 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec mpeg2video -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -me_method epzs -b 2600k -bt 256k -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.141:8554**

streaming works successfully using this command. Here IP address 192.168.1.141 is the ip address of my client pc. i can play live streaming on client side using vlc successfully.

But Issue is after some time encoding and streaming on server stop automatically. And command hangs there.

Output on server is as below:

```
$ avconv -f video4linux2 -s 160x120 -v debug -i /dev/video0 -vcodec mpeg2video -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -me_method epzs -b 2600k -bt 256k -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.141:8554
avconv version 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 22 2014 02:13:15 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --arch=arm --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.10-1+rpi1' --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/usr --disable-yasm --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil    51. 22. 2 / 51. 22. 2
  libavcodec   53. 35. 0 / 53. 35. 0
  libavformat  53. 21. 1 / 53. 21. 1
  libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
  libavfilter   2. 15. 0 /  2. 15. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
[video4linux2 @ 0x54d7a0] [4]Capabilities: 84000001
[video4linux2 @ 0x54d7a0] The V4L2 driver changed the pixel format from 0x32315559 to 0x56595559
    Last message repeated 1 times
[video4linux2 @ 0x54d7a0] The V4L2 driver changed the pixel format from 0x50323234 to 0x56595559
[video4linux2 @ 0x54d7a0] The V4L2 driver set input_id: 0, input: Camera 1
[rawvideo @ 0x54f860] err{or,}_recognition separate: 1; 1
[rawvideo @ 0x54f860] err{or,}_recognition combined: 1; 1
[video4linux2 @ 0x54d7a0] All info found
[video4linux2 @ 0x54d7a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, video4linux2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 21891.364784, bitrate: 9216 kb/s
    Stream #0.0, 1, 1/1000000: Video: rawvideo, yuyv422, 160x120, 1/30, 9216 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
[buffer @ 0x54f220] w:160 h:120 pixfmt:yuyv422
[avsink @ 0x54d740] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x54f7e0] w:160 h:120 fmt:yuyv422 -> w:160 h:120 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[mpeg2video @ 0x54ea60] err{or,}_recognition separate: 1; 1
[mpeg2video @ 0x54ea60] err{or,}_recognition combined: 1; 1
[mpeg2video @ 0x54ea60] detected 1 logical cores
[mpeg2video @ 0x54ea60] Unsupported bit depth: 0
[rawvideo @ 0x54f860] err{or,}_recognition separate: 1; 1
[rawvideo @ 0x54f860] err{or,}_recognition combined: 1; 1
Output #0, rtp, to 'rtp://192.168.1.141:8554':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0, 0, 1/90000: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 160x120, 1/25, q=2-31, 2600 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mpeg2video)
SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.141
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 53.21.1
m=video 8554 RTP/AVP 32
b=AS:2600

Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
*** drop!
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** 1 dup!
*** 16 dup! fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    1027kB time=5.24 bitrate=1605.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=2    
*** drop!
    Last message repeated 11 times
*** drop!49 fps= 26 q=2.0 size=    1059kB time=5.92 bitrate=1464.9kbits/s dup=17 drop=14    
    Last message repeated 2 times
*** drop!76 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    2022kB time=11.00 bitrate=1505.7kbits/s dup=17 drop=17    
*** drop!48 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    4086kB time=21.88 bitrate=1529.8kbits/s dup=17 drop=18    
*** 1 dup!
*** 1 dup!0 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    4171kB time=22.36 bitrate=1528.2kbits/s dup=18 drop=19    
*** 1 dup!1 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    4859kB time=26.00 bitrate=1530.8kbits/s dup=19 drop=19    
*** 1 dup!0 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    5152kB time=27.56 bitrate=1531.5kbits/s dup=20 drop=19    
*** 1 dup!3 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    5250kB time=28.08 bitrate=1531.7kbits/s dup=21 drop=19    
*** drop!64 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    7215kB time=38.52 bitrate=1534.5kbits/s dup=22 drop=19    
*** 1 dup!6 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    7306kB time=39.00 bitrate=1534.6kbits/s dup=22 drop=20    
*** drop!07 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=    8288kB time=44.24 bitrate=1534.7kbits/s dup=23 drop=20    
*** 1 dup!0 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=   10054kB time=53.56 bitrate=1537.8kbits/s dup=23 drop=21    
*** 1 dup!9 fps= 25 q=2.0 size=   10342kB time=55.12 bitrate=1537.1kbits/s dup=24 drop=21    
    Last message repeated 1 times
*** drop!93 fps= 25 q=1.6 size=   10445kB time=55.68 bitrate=1536.7kbits/s dup=26 drop=21    
*** 1 dup!
*** 7036829 dup! 25 q=2.0 size=   10630kB time=56.68 bitrate=1536.4kbits/s dup=27 drop=22
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Output of **v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext** command is as below:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
```

Comment: Can you show the complete output of: `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`?